# Three.js quaternion slerp gives bad result near poles

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, quaternions

Video example: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18Ep4i1JMs7QvW9m-3U4oyQ4sM0CfIFzP/view

What you can see here is that I have the world position of a ray hitting the globe under the mouse. Then I `lookAt()` with a `THREE.Group` to that position to get a quaternion with the correct rotation. The red dot always under my mouse proves that this quaternion is fine. Next, from the quaternion that represents the big yellow dome's center I use `rotateTowards` (which uses slerp internally, and I tried using directly the slerp method, but that gave me the same results) towards the mouse position's quaternion (the red dot) and set this quaternion as the rotation to the blue dot that's been following the mouse. This in theory should always "stick" to that dome when my mouse is farther away. You can see that it is indeed "sticking" to it when I'm doing these closer to the southern hemisphere. But near the north pole it goes haywire. It calculates shorter distances like it should, and not even on the correct great circle.

Relevant code:

```js
// using hammerjs pan events I send an event to the blue sphere with the position on the sphere whats under the mouse, event.point is correct, the red sphere always under the mouse proves this.

this.helperGroup.lookAt(event.point); // To get the requested rotation
const p = this.helperGroup.quaternion.clone(); // helpergroup is just an empty group in (0, 0, 0) to get quaternions with lookAt more easily
// p is now a rotation towards the point under the mouse

const requestedDistance = dome.quaternion.angleTo(p); // dome is the center of the yellow dome in the video, allowedDistance is the arc-length of said dome in radians.
// The reason I rotate the parent of blueSphere because its parent is another group in (0, 0, 0) and the (relative) position of the blue sphere is (0, 0, 1), the planets radius is 1 too.
if (allowedDistance >= requestedDistance) {
    blueSphere.parent.lookAt(event.point);
} else {
    blueSphere.parent.quaternion.copy(
        dome.quaternion.clone().rotateTowards(p, allowedAngle)
    );
}

//  this snippet is heavily modified for the sake of an example.
```

## Update, and different approach:

I originally used this `lookAt()` and rotation based placements to avoid as much math as I can. But it back-lashed. So now I'm doing it correctly simply with cartesian coordinates, normal vectors and simple axis based rotations. (Turned out using math is actually simpler than avoiding it)

```js
const requestedDistance = blueSphere.angleTo(event.point);
let norm = dome.position.clone().cross(event.point).normalize();
if (allowedDistance >= requestedDistance) {
    blueSphere.position.set(event.point); // Not using a group as parent anymore
} else {
    blueSphere.position.set(dome.position.clone()
                            .applyAxisAngle(norm, allowedAngle);
}
```

Comment: Would it possible for us to see the relevant pieces of the code you have so far?
Also, what is your goal in doing this? Try to sum up in a few words what you want to achieve and perhaps someone would be able to give a different approach to your problem.

Comment: I added an example. The first problem I realize is that `.angleTo` gives bad result because if it wouldn't I'd see correct result all inside the yellow dome and then the bad results would only appear when I'd 'request' a relocation beyond that.

Comment: As I suspected, using the world positions and the `Vector3`'s `angleTo` instead of Quaternions the `requestedDistance` is now calculated correctly and the bad results only appear beyond that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A singularity near the poles is part of the nature of the quaternion slerp function; it can't be avoided except by using a different approach.  Jonathan Blow's article, "[Understanding Slerp, Then Not Using It](http://number-none.com/product/Understanding%20Slerp,%20Then%20Not%20Using%20It/)", discusses the slerp function and its problems, and suggests that an alternative to slerp (normalized lerp or `nlerp`) is the quaternion interpolator to be preferred most of the time.

Note that even the C++ code for slerp in that article acknowledges the singularity present in the slerp function.

Comment: Thank you, I suspected that it's something with the nature of these things. I did already implemented a solution with a different approach. Updating the question shortly.